# MongoDB - How can I get the size of find() using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm writing a server-side code using node.js, I'm trying to get the size of the returned data ( find() ).
This is my code

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    User.find({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    }, function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                error: "Couldn't find the user"
            })
        } else {
            users.toArray(function(error, n) {
                if (n.length == 0) {
                    console.log("User not found!");
                }

            });
            res.send(users);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but in order to prevent [NoSQL-Injection](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html) you may use library [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize) or use at least `find({username: JSON.stringify(req.body.username)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find()` returns an array of objects, so you can just do `.length` on it

```
console.log(users.length)
```